# Android GoogleMaps: GeoJsonLayer.features change the order of geojson file

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a `location` geojson file as below:

```
{
"type":"FeatureCollection", 
"features":[
  {"type":"Feature","properties":{"name":"West"}},
  {"type":"Feature","properties":{"name":"East"}},
  {"type":"Feature","properties":{"name":"North"}}
]}
```

```
var geoJsonLayer = GeoJsonLayer(googleMap, R.raw.location, this)

geoJsonLayer.features.forEach {
   print(it.properties)
}
```

I found the order of `geoJsonLayer.features` becomes:

```
{
  "East",
  "West",
  "North"
}
```

The [official doc](https://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/data/Layer.html#getFeatures--) does not state if it returns feature elements randomly.

I wanted to iterate the `geoJsonLayer.features` to get the `properties` in the order shown in the `location` file.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `geoJsonLayer.features` is a `HashMap` and iteration order depends of keys. Theoretically you can replace `HashMap` with `LinkedHashMap` in `BiMultiMap.java` class of utils library

```
//public class BiMultiMap<K> extends HashMap<K, Object> {
public class BiMultiMap<K> extends LinkedHashMap<K, Object> {
```

but seems easiest way is to sort values of `geoJsonLayer.features` by custom comparator.